# How to subscribe to service in Angular 2 few times in one component?

Tags: angular

My service works just fine the first time. When it's called again later it doesn't work. I have the service in NgModule

Here is my code

```
  this._portService.getPortList().subscribe(
      (data) => {
          this.len = data['interfaces-state'].length;
              for (this.i = 0; this.i<this.len;this.i++){
                  this.portListJson.push(data['interfaces-state'][this.i].interface);
                  }
                this.removeONUPorts();
                this.addNames();
              });
```

And my constructor

```
 constructor(private _portService:PortsService, private elRef: ElementRef){
        }
```

When I try to call the same code from different function it doesn't work.

My service

```
  getPortList(){
   return this._http.get(environment.api + "restconf/data/ietf-interfaces:interfaces-state/interface?fields=")
     .map(response => response.json());
};
```

My second call

```
 setONUList(port: Port){
      this.clearLists();
         this._portService.getPortList().subscribe(
             (data) => {
                 this.len = data['interfaces-state'].length;
                     for (this.i = 0; this.i<this.len;this.i++){
                         this.portListJson.push(data['interfaces-state'][this.i].interface);
                         }
                       this.removeONUPorts();
                       this.addNames();
                     });

}
```

Comment: Update question with your second subscribe for now its seems fine

Comment: Are you calling the right url in getPortList(). You can check the data coming back by consoling. Like try this to check: `getPortList(){
   return this._http.get(environment.api + "restconf/data/ietf-interfaces:interfaces-state/interface?fields=")
     .map(response => response.json()).do(data=>console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));
};`

Comment: I did, it doesn't subscribe. On debug it skips that part

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.  I don't understand why you need 2 subscriptions from the same component.  Typically I instantiate my subscriptions in a component's constructor or ngOnInit method, then map the value from the subscription to a local value in the component, which can then be accessed from any component method.

So I would do something like this:

```
      this._portService.getPortList().subscribe(
          (data) => {
                       this.localDataVar = data;
                       ...
                  });
```

then in your component method you can access your localDataVar variable

```
 setONUList(port: Port){
      this.clearLists();
      this.someFunction(this.localDataVar);  //here you'll have last emitted value of data
}
```

Or another way is to simply access the current observable value in your subsequent methods like this:

```
 setONUList(port: Port){
      this.clearLists();
      let curVal = this._portService.getPortList().getValue();
}
```

I don't understand why you would need or want two identical subscriptions from the same component.

Comment: I needed it because I need refresh button

Comment: that doesn't mean you need two subscriptions.  You just need one, and a method that updates the value that the subscription is emitting.

Comment: Now it doesn't get called at all

Comment: you should subscribe in ngOnInit, map the value emitted from the subscription to a local component variable.  Then in your sonOnUList method use the local component variable.  There is not need for a second subscription.

Comment: What if the json gets updated in meantime, while I am in the component

Comment: I solved it, the problem was the I got the data while still in subscriber